# Spontaneously Broken Approximate Symmetry, Weinberg 19.4, QFT 2

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry-breaking, chirality

I am having difficult time understanding part of 19.4 section where Weinberg introduces the symmetry breaking terms for $SU(2)\times SU(2)$ symmetric theory for $u,d$ quarks, specifically, he adds (eq. 19.4.34):

> \begin{align}
> H_1 = m_u \bar{u}u + m_d \bar{d}d = (m_u+m_d) \Phi_4^{+} + (m_u - m_d)\Phi_3^{-}
> \end{align}

where
$\Phi_4^+, \Phi_3^-$ are spatial scalars that are introduced, where now $\Phi_n^{\pm}$ are 4-vectors under SO(4) representation of $SU(2)\times SU(2)$ group. But this perturbation creates a vacuum alignment condition, which is:

\begin{align}
0 = <\Phi_2^{-}>_0 = <\Phi_1^{-}>_0 = <\Phi_1^{+}>_0 = <\Phi_2^{+}>_0 = (m_u +m_d) <\Phi_3^{+}>_0 + (m_d-m_u)<\Phi_4^{-}>_0.
\end{align}

After this Weinberg looses me, the paragraph after 19.4.42 is not clear to me. Please let me know if you understand it.

It says in the beginning:

> We have been assuming that in the absence of u and d quark masses, the symmetry SU(2) $\times$ SU(2) is spontaneously broken in such a way as to preserve unbroken the $SU(2)$ symmetry generated by $\vec{T}$ as well as parity in which case $<\Phi_n^+>_0$ points in the four-direction and $<\Phi_n^->_0 = 0$.

This is unclear to me and after this probably stems from this. But if you have an idea or another resource that deals with the same content, please let me know.

Comment: Weinberg is turgid/exhausting on this. One assumes you have gone through and appreciated [Scherer's standard introduction](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0210398). Due diligence!

Comment: Weinberg aligns the vacuum as in his (19.3.6), and $\Phi_4^+$ is an isosinglet, and scalar, but the scalar $\Phi_3^-$ obviously isn't. He shows you the Dashen formula for the pion masses works out as in  standard discussions, but he is dandifying the argument for the impressionable to make it look general. It helps to know the truly banal answers in advance.

Comment: Oh thank you for the resource; no, my first introduction was through Weinberg only. This is very helpful.